# How can I upload a new updated MCRSS plugin to my app?

Tags: css, buildfire

I want few changes on my APP, support told -Our platform allows for incredible customization by a developer with common languages like HTML, CSS, and Javascript.
Developing on the platform is done with the new SDK that can be found here on github. You can see more about developing the customization you need here: http://buildfire.com/developers/
As always

Downloaded MCRSS on my PC and made few changes Like on home page i dont want to show date below title -

i just added css property in list-item-date {display none:}

and we dont want Title and author name get trimmed , i just removed trim code.

Now New Updated MCRSS plugin ready at my PC.
How can i upload that on my APP.
Please tell me steps

Comment: Please provide a code sample for your case, your question is not enough to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to customize the Media Center RSS plugin. You have two options:

1. Create a pull request on the [repo](https://github.com/BuildFire/pluginMediaCenterRSS/pulls).
2. Create an account on the [developer portal](http://dev.buildfire.com/), and upload your own custom version of the plugin.

For option one, you'll have to make your changes generic so that your pull request will be accepted. It might include making some of the options configurable from the control side. The main benefit is that moving forward the plugin will include your changes and any future bug fixes or enhancements will automatically be included.

The second option is easier to do if you're not as familiar with Git, and/or don't want to spend the time to make the options configurable. You just create an developer account and upload your custom plugin. (It will require you to rename the plugin to something unique.)

Hope that helps.